# RecyclerView.Adapter never calls onCreateViewHolder

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter

After searching for hours I can't find a solution to my problem. I have the following classes:

Main activity:

```
RecyclerView rvIdeas = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recView1);

// Initialize ideas
DaoSession daosession = ((App) getApplication()).getDaoSession();
IdeaDao ideadao = daosession.getIdeaDao();
ideas = (ArrayList<Idea>) ideadao.loadAll();
// Set layout manager to position the items
rvIdeas.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
// Create adapter passing in the list of ideas
IdeaAdapter adapter = new IdeaAdapter(this, ideas);
// Attach the adapter to the recyclerview to populate items
rvIdeas.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Then the adapter:

```
public class IdeaAdapter extends
    RecyclerView.Adapter<IdeaAdapter.ViewHolder> {

// Provide a direct reference to each of the views within a data item
// Used to cache the views within the item layout for fast access
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView ideaname;
    public TextView docCount;
    public TextView last_mod;

    // We also create a constructor that accepts the entire item row
    // and does the view lookups to find each subview
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        // Stores the itemView in a public final member variable that can be used
        // to access the context from any ViewHolder instance.
        super(itemView);

        ideaname = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.main_idea_name);
        docCount = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.idea_documents);
        last_mod = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.idea_last_edited);

    }
}
// Store a member variable for the ideas
private List<Idea> ideas;
// Store the context for easy access
private Context mContext;

// Pass in the idea array into the constructor
public IdeaAdapter(Context context, List<Idea> ideaList) {
    ideas = ideaList;
    mContext = context;
}

// Easy access to the context object in the recyclerview
private Context getContext() {
    return mContext;
}

// Usually involves inflating a layout from XML and returning the holder
@Override
public IdeaAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    Context context = parent.getContext();
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    // Inflate the custom layout
    View ideaView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_idea, parent, false);

    // Return a new holder instance
    return new ViewHolder(ideaView);
}

// Involves populating data into the item through holder
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(IdeaAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    // Get the data model based on position
    Idea idea = ideas.get(position);

    // Set item views based on your views and data model
    viewHolder.ideaname.setText(idea.getName());

    String docs = R.string.media + idea.getName();
    viewHolder.docCount.setText(docs);

    viewHolder.last_mod.setText(idea.getLast_modified().toString());
}

// Returns the total count of items in the list
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return ideas.size();
}
}
```

And the .xml of fragment_main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:app1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:visibility="visible"
tools:context=".view.fragments.MainFragment">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rvIdea"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:visibility="visible" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_insert"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="325dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="325dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="465dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="false"
    android:baselineAlignBottom="false"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
    android:onClick="addFABclick"
    app1:pressedTranslationZ="24dp"
    app:layout_behavior=".view.animation.ScrollAwareFABBehavior"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/material_add_white" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Last but not least the layout for the recyclerview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/main_idea_name"
    android:layout_width="210dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/idea_documents"
    android:layout_width="210dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/main_idea_name" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/idea_share"
    android:layout_width="28dp"
    android:layout_height="31dp"
    app:srcCompat="?attr/actionModeShareDrawable"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/idea_go_inside"
    android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="22dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/share"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/idea_go_inside"
    android:layout_width="29dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/material_arrow_right"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/go_next"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/idea_trash"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/idea_share"
    android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="14dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/idea_documents"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    android:contentDescription="@string/trash"/>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/idea_last_edited"
    android:layout_width="210dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorSecondaryText"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/idea_documents" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The problem is that `onBindViewHolder` and `onCreateViewHolder` are never called. `getItemCount` returns something > 0 and there are no null pointers or nested scrolls. The recyclerview displays nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I've such experience when my `RecyclerView` was invisible or hidden by another view. Check that `RecyclerView` is visible in all meanings when you are render it.

Also you can try to refresh adapter of `RecyclerView` by `notifyDataSetChanged()` method.

Comment: I'm confused by a couple of details in the question. The code initialising the RecyclerView is under the heading of 'Main activity' and the RecyclerView has id `recView1` but the layout is for a fragment and the RecyclerView has id `rvIdea`.

Comment: @comrade There should be no other view which hide the `RecyclerView` because I see the `FloatingActionButton` but no `RecyclerView`.

@LewisMcGeary Shall I initialise the recyclerview in the fragment?

Comment: Thanks for your help, I found my stupid problem. As I use fragments I should initialise the RecyclerView in the fragment and NOT in the main activity. Thanks at @LewisMcGeary I checked this after your comment.